# C++ fwrite and fread for string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, fwrite, fread

here's the piece of code that writes a string in a binary file:

```
std::string s("Hello");
unsigned int N(s.size());
fwrite(&N,sizeof(N), 1 ,bfile);
fwrite(s.c_str(),1, N ,bfile);
fflush(bfile);
```

the piece to read the string:

```
std::string new_s("");
unsigned int N(0);
fread(&N,sizeof(N),1,bfile);
char* c(new char[N+1]);
fread(c,1,N,bfile);
c[N] = '\0';
new_s = c;
delete[] c;
```

Questions :

- is there a simpler way to do that ?
- when I write/read the file, should i take into account the null character `'\0'` that comes from the `c_str()` ?

I have a side question which is related to `char* c(new char[N])` :

- i know that c++ doesn't allow to create a static array with for instance int `a[size_of_array]`, so the solution is to use a pointer created with `new[]` and deleted with `delete[]`. is this the only solution (if i can't use a `std::vector < int >` ), and would this solution be efficient ?

Comment: Is it a requirement to write the size in the file or is that just for the read logic?

Comment: I think you should be using the [iostream library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)

Comment: why should i use iostream instead of fstream ?

Comment: if i don't save the size of the string in the file, how can i read it later ?

Comment: Instead of using a type like `unsigned int` for the size, which may change in different implementations, you should use something like `std::uint32_t`, or `std::uint64_t`, which will always be 32 bits or 64 bits.  You also need to be careful about endianness if you intend these data files to be usable across a wide range of platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `std::string::size()` does not account for the NUL character, so your binary file will not contain that. Your strategy for serializing is fine (size first, followed by set of characters.)

As for reading, it's possibly better to use a `vector` (in c++03, or `string` in c++11 directly).

So once you've determined the size (`N`), then:

```
std::vector<char> content(N, 0); // substitute std::string if possible
fread(&content[0],1,N,bfile);
// Construct the string (skip this, if you read into the string directly)
std::string s(content.begin(), content.end());
```

Comment: It's possible to resize the string first and then read directly into it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        std::string someString = argc > 1? argv[1]:"Hello World";
        std::ofstream out("fileName.txt",std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        size_t len = someString.size();
        out.write((const char*)&len, 4);
        out<<someString; // out.write(someString.c_str(), someString.size())
        out.flush();
        out.close();


        std::ifstream in("fileName.txt",std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
        in.read((char*)&len, 4);
        char *buf = new char[len];
        in.read(buf, len);
        std::string someStringRead(buf, len);
        delete[] buf; // this might be better with scoped_array
        in.close();

        std::cout<<"Read ["<<someStringRead<<"]"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it only sensible to assume there might be other things in the file, and that the string might be any length, so that information needs to be stored in the file somehow.

Comment: yes the file contains a lot of different data of different type and the string can indeed be of any length...

Comment: yeah, that's just a matter of writing your fields. e.g. write(&len, sizeof(int)) before string. usual practice is <type-code><len><data>. I posted the snippet to demonstrate how to use iostream/fstream for I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping to your choice of cstdio , better would be:

```
fprintf(bfile,"%d ",N);
fwrite(s.data(),1,N,bfile);
if ( ferror(bfile) ) die("writing bfile");
```

```
char c;
if ( fscanf(bfile,"%d%c",&N,&c)  != 2 
  || c != ' ' ) die("bfile metadata");
vector<char> buf(N);
if ( fread(&buf[0],1,N,bfile) != N ) die("bfile data");
s.assign(&buf[0],N);
```

Binary serialization formats are a recipe for pain. Avoid them entirely in the absence of concrete evidence that they'll get you some benefit worth days or weeks of your time.

C++ strings can actually include null bytes.  Serialization code isn't the place to impose limits.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <fstream.h>
...
char buffer[100];
ofstream bfile("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
bfile.write (buffer, 100);
```